Varnish "Backend fetch failed" with fail errno 0 (Success)
we provide a website using Plesk managed environment with nginx as reverse proxy to varnish (6.2) and apache as backend. There is no problem.
Now we have a new server running on Almalinux 9, installed dedicated Varnish (6.6.2) as a service on the server and did the exact same configuration:

Nginx on Port 80
proxy_pass to varnish via http://127.0.0.1:6081;
varnish vcl

backend default {
    .host = "<server_ip>";
    .port = "7080";
    .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
}

Varnish Service
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -a :6081 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -p default_ttl=3600 -p default_grace=3600 -p http_resp_hdr_len=131072 -p http_resp_size=262144 -p workspace_backend=524288 -p workspace_session=2048 -s malloc,512m 

Apache running on port 7080

If i test just the Apache with curl -I -H "Host: <domainname>" http://<server_ip>:7080/ everything works fine and i get the test page.
The same on the nginx server curl -I -H "Host: <domainname>" http://<server_ip>:80/ results in an 503 Backend fetch failed.
So i dived into the varnishlog -g request and get this information:

*   << Request  >> 65637
-   Begin          req 65636 rxreq
-   Timestamp      Start: 1725271548.854662 0.000000 0.000000
-   Timestamp      Req: 1725271548.854662 0.000000 0.000000
-   VCL_use        boot
-   ReqStart       127.0.0.1 48176 a0
-   ReqMethod      GET
-   ReqURL         /
-   ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.0
-   ReqHeader      Host: <domain.com>
-   ReqHeader      X-Real-IP: <server-ip>
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: <server-ip>
-   ReqHeader      Connection: close
-   ReqHeader      User-Agent: curl/7.76.1
-   ReqHeader      Accept: */*
-   ReqUnset       X-Forwarded-For: <server-ip>
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: <server-ip>, 127.0.0.1
-   VCL_call       RECV
-   ReqHeader      grace: none
-   ReqURL         /
-   VCL_return     hash
-   VCL_call       HASH
-   VCL_return     lookup
-   VCL_call       MISS
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   Link           bereq 65638 fetch
-   Timestamp      Fetch: 1725271548.854857 0.000195 0.000195
-   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
-   RespStatus     503
-   RespReason     Backend fetch failed
-   RespHeader     Date: Mon, 02 Sep 2024 10:05:48 GMT
-   RespHeader     Server: Varnish
-   RespHeader     content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
-   RespHeader     Retry-After: 5
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish: 65637
-   RespHeader     Age: 0
-   RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.6)
-   VCL_call       DELIVER
-   RespHeader     X-Cache: MISS
-   RespUnset      Age: 0
-   RespHeader     Pragma: no-cache
-   RespHeader     Expires: -1
-   RespHeader     Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
-   RespUnset      Server: Varnish
-   RespUnset      X-Varnish: 65637
-   RespUnset      Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.6)
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Timestamp      Process: 1725271548.854876 0.000214 0.000019
-   Filters
-   RespHeader     Content-Length: 282
-   RespHeader     Connection: close
-   Timestamp      Resp: 1725271548.854943 0.000281 0.000067
-   ReqAcct        153 0 153 279 282 561
-   End
**  << BeReq    >> 65638
--  Begin          bereq 65637 fetch
--  VCL_use        boot
--  Timestamp      Start: 1725271548.854722 0.000000 0.000000
--  BereqMethod    GET
--  BereqURL       /
--  BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.0
--  BereqHeader    Host: <domain.com>
--  BereqHeader    X-Real-IP: <server-ip>
--  BereqHeader    User-Agent: curl/7.76.1
--  BereqHeader    Accept: */*
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-For: <server-ip>, 127.0.0.1
--  BereqHeader    grace: none
--  BereqHeader    Accept-Encoding: gzip
--  BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.1
--  BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 65638
--  VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
--  VCL_return     fetch
--  Timestamp      Fetch: 1725271548.854732 0.000010 0.000010
--  FetchError     backend default: fail errno 13 (Permission denied)
--  Timestamp      Beresp: 1725271548.854823 0.000101 0.000091
--  Timestamp      Error: 1725271548.854824 0.000102 0.000000
--  BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
--  BerespStatus   503
--  BerespReason   Backend fetch failed
--  BerespHeader   Date: Mon, 02 Sep 2024 10:05:48 GMT
--  BerespHeader   Server: Varnish
--  VCL_call       BACKEND_ERROR
--  BerespHeader   content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
--  BerespHeader   Retry-After: 5
--  VCL_return     deliver
--  Storage        malloc Transient
--  Length         282
--  BereqAcct      0 0 0 0 0 0
--  End

The error sometimes output
--  FetchError     backend default: fail errno 0 (Success)

Nginx Config for this domain
#ATTENTION!
#
#DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE BECAUSE IT WAS GENERATED AUTOMATICALLY,
#SO ALL YOUR CHANGES WILL BE LOST THE NEXT TIME THE FILE IS GENERATED.

server {
    listen <server-ip>:443 ssl;
    http2 on;

    server_name <domain.com>;
    server_name www.<domain.com>;
    server_name ipv4.<domain.com>;

    ssl_certificate             /usr/local/psa/var/certificates/scfEiYV92;
    ssl_certificate_key         /usr/local/psa/var/certificates/scfEiYV92;

    client_max_body_size 134217728;

    # mailconfig
    location ~* ^/autodiscover/autodiscover\.xml$ {
        try_files $uri @mad;
    }
    location ~* ^(/\.well-known/autoconfig)?/mail/config\-v1\.1\.xml$ {
        try_files $uri @mad;
    }

    location  ~* ^/email\.mobileconfig$ {
        try_files $uri @mad;
    }

    location @mad {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /mailconfig/ break;

        proxy_pass                          http://127.0.0.1:8880;
        proxy_set_header X-Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Request-URI      $request_uri;
    }
    # mailconfig

    access_log "/var/www/vhosts/system/<domain.com>/logs/proxy_access_ssl_log";
    error_log "/var/www/vhosts/system/<domain.com>/logs/proxy_error_log";

    root "/var/www/vhosts/<domain.com>/httpdocs";

    #extension performance-booster begin
    # Additional directives added by Plesk Optimization Settings

    # Additional directives added by Plesk Optimization Settings
    #extension performance-booster end

    #extension sslit begin

    #extension sslit end

    #extension letsencrypt begin
    location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs;

        types { }
        default_type text/plain;

        satisfy any;
        auth_basic off;
        allow all;

        location ~ ^/\.well-known/acme-challenge.*/\. {
            deny all;
        }
    }
    #extension letsencrypt end

    error_page 400 "/error_docs/bad_request.html";
    error_page 401 "/error_docs/unauthorized.html";
    error_page 403 "/error_docs/forbidden.html";
    error_page 404 "/error_docs/not_found.html";
    error_page 500 "/error_docs/internal_server_error.html";
    error_page 405 "/error_docs/method_not_allowed.html";
    error_page 406 "/error_docs/not_acceptable.html";
    error_page 407 "/error_docs/proxy_authentication_required.html";
    error_page 412 "/error_docs/precondition_failed.html";
    error_page 414 "/error_docs/request_uri_too_long.html";
    error_page 415 "/error_docs/unsupported_media_type.html";
    error_page 501 "/error_docs/not_implemented.html";
    error_page 502 "/error_docs/bad_gateway.html";
    error_page 503 "/error_docs/maintenance.html";

    location ^~ /error_docs {
        root "/var/www/vhosts/<domain.com>";
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://<server-ip>:7081;
        proxy_hide_header upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Accel-Internal /internal-nginx-static-location;
        access_log off;

    }

    location ^~ /internal-nginx-static-location/ {
        alias /var/www/vhosts/<domain.com>/httpdocs/;
        internal;
    }

    location ~ ^/~(.+?)(/.*?\.php)(/.*)?$ {
        alias /var/www/vhosts/<domain.com>/web_users/$1/$2;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.php)(/?.+)$;
        try_files $uri $fastcgi_script_name =404;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_pass "unix:/var/www/vhosts/system/<domain.com>/php-fpm.sock";
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;

    }

    location ~ ^/~(.+?)(/.*)?$ {
        proxy_pass https://<server-ip>:7081;
        proxy_hide_header upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Accel-Internal /internal-nginx-static-location;
        access_log off;

    }

    location ~ \.php(/.*)?$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.php)(/?.+)$;
        try_files $uri $fastcgi_script_name =404;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_pass "unix:/var/www/vhosts/system/<domain.com>/php-fpm.sock";
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;

    }

    disable_symlinks if_not_owner "from=/var/www/vhosts/<domain.com>";


    include "/var/www/vhosts/system/<domain.com>/conf/vhost_nginx.conf";
}

server {
    listen <server-ip>:80;

    server_name <domain.com>;
    server_name www.<domain.com>;
    server_name ipv4.<domain.com>;

    client_max_body_size 134217728;

    # mailconfig
    location ~* ^/autodiscover/autodiscover\.xml$ {
        try_files $uri @mad;
    }
    location ~* ^(/\.well-known/autoconfig)?/mail/config\-v1\.1\.xml$ {
        try_files $uri @mad;
    }

    location  ~* ^/email\.mobileconfig$ {
        try_files $uri @mad;
    }

    location @mad {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /mailconfig/ break;

        proxy_pass                          http://127.0.0.1:8880;
        proxy_set_header X-Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Request-URI      $request_uri;
    }
    # mailconfig

    access_log "/var/www/vhosts/system/<domain.com>/logs/proxy_access_log";
    error_log "/var/www/vhosts/system/<domain.com>/logs/proxy_error_log";

    root "/var/www/vhosts/<domain.com>/httpdocs";

    #extension performance-booster begin
    # Additional directives added by Plesk Optimization Settings

    # Additional directives added by Plesk Optimization Settings
    #extension performance-booster end

    #extension sslit begin

    #extension sslit end

    #extension letsencrypt begin
    location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs;

        types { }
        default_type text/plain;

        satisfy any;
        auth_basic off;
        allow all;

        location ~ ^/\.well-known/acme-challenge.*/\. {
            deny all;
        }
    }
    #extension letsencrypt end

    error_page 400 "/error_docs/bad_request.html";
    error_page 401 "/error_docs/unauthorized.html";
    error_page 403 "/error_docs/forbidden.html";
    error_page 404 "/error_docs/not_found.html";
    error_page 500 "/error_docs/internal_server_error.html";
    error_page 405 "/error_docs/method_not_allowed.html";
    error_page 406 "/error_docs/not_acceptable.html";
    error_page 407 "/error_docs/proxy_authentication_required.html";
    error_page 412 "/error_docs/precondition_failed.html";
    error_page 414 "/error_docs/request_uri_too_long.html";
    error_page 415 "/error_docs/unsupported_media_type.html";
    error_page 501 "/error_docs/not_implemented.html";
    error_page 502 "/error_docs/bad_gateway.html";
    error_page 503 "/error_docs/maintenance.html";

    location ^~ /error_docs {
        root "/var/www/vhosts/<domain.com>";
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://<server-ip>:7080;
        proxy_set_header Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Accel-Internal /internal-nginx-static-location;
        access_log off;

    }

    location ^~ /internal-nginx-static-location/ {
        alias /var/www/vhosts/<domain.com>/httpdocs/;
        internal;
    }

    location ~ ^/~(.+?)(/.*?\.php)(/.*)?$ {
        alias /var/www/vhosts/<domain.com>/web_users/$1/$2;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.php)(/?.+)$;
        try_files $uri $fastcgi_script_name =404;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_pass "unix:/var/www/vhosts/system/<domain.com>/php-fpm.sock";
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;

    }

    location ~ ^/~(.+?)(/.*)?$ {
        proxy_pass http://<server-ip>:7080;
        proxy_set_header Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Accel-Internal /internal-nginx-static-location;
        access_log off;

    }

    location ~ \.php(/.*)?$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.php)(/?.+)$;
        try_files $uri $fastcgi_script_name =404;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_pass "unix:/var/www/vhosts/system/<domain.com>/php-fpm.sock";
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;

    }

    disable_symlinks if_not_owner "from=/var/www/vhosts/<domain.com>";


    include "/var/www/vhosts/system/<domain.com>/conf/vhost_nginx.conf";
}

I tried different vcl config, but nothing changes so i am using the default one at the moment
backend default {
    .host = "<server_ip>";
    .port = "7080";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    # Happens before we check if we have this in cache already.
    #
    # Typically you clean up the request here, removing cookies you don't need,
    # rewriting the request, etc.
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    # Happens after we have read the response headers from the backend.
    #
    # Here you clean the response headers, removing silly Set-Cookie headers
    # and other mistakes your backend does.
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    # Happens when we have all the pieces we need, and are about to send the
    # response to the client.
    #
    # You can do accounting or modifying the final object here.
}

The Backend Fetch doesnt work, but what about fail errno 0 (Success) or fail errno 13 (Permission denied) ?
Does anybody has an advice for me, what to change?
Varnish communicate with Backend

Can you provide some more details please? Can you provide the full varnishlog output for the transaction: both the complete output of the initial request, and the complete output of the backend request (of which you provided an extract). Please also provide your for VCL and the Nginx config you use to proxy to Varnish. I have some ideas, but without the proper input, it's impossible to validate those ideas.

@ThijsFeryn i just updated my post. I discover, that the FetchError is fail errno 13 (Permission denied) or  fail errno 0 (Success)

Scenario 1: use HTTP/1.1 proxying
While the error message doesn't make a lot of sense to me, I do see something that might cause problems.
By default Nginx uses HTTP/1.0 when it proxies. This could cause the issue, although I'm not 100% sure.
Please set proxy_http_version 1.1; in your Nginx proxy configuration and try again.
Scenario 2: backend not accessible
A more likely scenario is that the backend is simply not reachable from the Varnish server.
You say that curl -I -H "Host: <domainname>" http://<server_ip>:7080/ works fine.
I'd like you to try that on the Varnish server itself to see if you can successfully send requests, maybe even with extra an -vvv argument for higher verbosity.
Additionally, if the backend doesn't seem reachable, you could set up a health probe on your VCL backend definition to monitor it.
This is what that would look like with minimal configuration:
backend default {
    .host = "<server_ip>";
    .port = "7080";
    .probe = {
        .url = "/";
    }
}

See https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/reference/vcl-probe.html for more information about health probes.
Once you have a health probe in place you can monitor it using the following command:
varnishlog -g raw -i Backend_health

Here's an example of a successful probe:
0 Backend_health - default Still healthy 4---X-RH 8 3 8 0.001919 0.001830 "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"

And here is the spec for the Backend_health VSL tag, based on https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/reference/vsl.html#vsl-tags:
%s %s %s %s %u %u %u %f %f %s
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  +- Probe HTTP response / error information
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  +---- Average response time
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  +------- Response time
|  |  |  |  |  |  +---------- Probe window size
|  |  |  |  |  +------------- Probe threshold level
|  |  |  |  +---------------- Number of good probes in window
|  |  |  +------------------- Probe window bits
|  |  +---------------------- "healthy" or "sick"
|  +------------------------- "Back", "Still" or "Went"
+---------------------------- Backend name

This will allow you to have a real-time view of the status of backend in Varnish.

Scenario 1 unfortunately is not the correct answer. I would like to try scneario 2, but what do you mean with I'd like you to try that on the Varnish server itself to see if you can successfully send requests, maybe even with extra an -vvv argument for higher verbosity. How to request a backend call?

@Luco just SSH into the Varnish server and run curl -v -I -H "Host: <domainname>" http://<server_ip>:7080/. That's similar to what Varnish does internally when it proxies the request to Apache. I'm assuming that curl will give you some more details on what's going on.

ok to clarify: it is all on the same server. I installed varnish as service:
# systemctl status varnish
â varnish.service - Varnish Cache, a high-performance HTTP accelerator
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/varnish.service; disabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2024-09-02 13:23:29 CEST; 4s ago

So the curl -v -I -H "Host: <domainname>" http://<server_ip>:7080/ is allready from the same server

@Luco Can I assume <server_ip> is actually 127.0.0.1? Or are you using another IP address or Unix Domain Socket? Permission denied issues usually occur when a Unix Domain Socket connection fails or it could be a firewall, like SELinux, blocking the request.

@Luco https://www.seimaxim.com/linux/how-to-disable-selinux-in-centos-linux-and-almalinux describes how to disable & re-enable SELinux. Worth the try.

no <server_ip> was the public ip of the server, but your last advice pointed me to the problem. With disabled SELinux Varnish can access the apache server as backend! Do you know what it takes to allow it with enabled SELinux?

@Luco I don't have much experience with it, but we wrote an article about it for Varnish Enterprise. I guess most of it can be reused for Varnish Cache: https://docs.varnish-software.com/tutorials/selinux-faq/. Have a look at the troubleshooting section.
